# I want to flatten JSON column in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, normalize

I have an input dataframe df which is as follows:

```
id  e
1   {"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}
2   {"k1":"v3","k2":"v4"}
3   {"k1":"v5","k2":"v6"}
```

I want to "flatten" the column 'e' so that my resultant dataframe is:

```
id  e.k1    e.k2
1   v1  v2
2   v3  v4
3   v5  v6
```

How can I do this? I tried using json_normalize but did not have much success

Answer (score 16):

Here is a way to use [`pandas.io.json.json_normalize()`:](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df = df.join(json_normalize(df["e"].tolist()).add_prefix("e.")).drop(["e"], axis=1)
print(df)
#  e.k1 e.k2
#0   v1   v2
#1   v3   v4
#2   v5   v6
```

However, if you're column is actually a `str` and not a `dict`, then you'd first have to map it using `json.loads()`:

```
import json
df = df.join(json_normalize(df['e'].map(json.loads).tolist()).add_prefix('e.'))\
    .drop(['e'], axis=1)
```

Comment: You may want to `df = df.reset_index()` before `df.join` to make sure the rows are matched correctly.

Comment: @pault how would you adopt this if some of the rows are blank for the column with json.   Your solution works for me with all the rows have valid json but if I have any rows with a blank column I get an error :

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'items'

Answer (score 5):

If your column is not already a dictionary, you could use `map(json.loads)` and apply `pd.Series`:

```
s = df['e'].map(json.loads).apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('e.')
```

Or if it is already a dictionary, you can apply `pd.Series` directly:

```
s = df['e'].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('e.')
```

Finally use `pd.concat` to join back the other columns:

```
>>> pd.concat([df.drop(['e'], axis=1), s], axis=1).set_index('id')    
id e.k1 e.k2
1    v1   v2
2    v3   v4
3    v5   v6
```