# Read CSV with JSON feature

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a large CSV which includes JSON features (*location* here). For the first, say 100 lines, the file looks like this:

```
Time,location,labelA,labelB
2019-09-10,{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8},nan,nan
```

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680272/parsing-a-json-string-which-was-loaded-from-a-csv-using-pandas) to parse the *location* column. The solution basically defines a helper as:

```
def CustomParser(data):
    import json
    j1 = json.loads(data)
    return j1
```

and then

```
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv', nrows=100,converters={'location':CustomParser},header=0)
```

I get the following error which is related to JSON format:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

**Q1:** How can I parse the feature *location* onto new columns?

**Q2 (for general case):** For nrows>100 in the data, also the last features (labelA and labelB) have JSON formats with different key and value. How can I possibly read the entire CSV with parsing every feature which includes JSON (even partially)?

#### `test100v1.csv`

```
Zeit,device,Text,Typ,Position,Data,Data1,Data2
2019-09-10T12:13:24.000Z,CO 5052994,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":12.9975201,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:09:58Z","error":7.0,"lat":47.8258582},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:13:23.000Z,CO 5050450,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":14.3195367,"alt":260.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:12:37Z","error":10.0,"lat":48.2695571},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:13:21.000Z,CO 5050903,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":15.2678846,"alt":494.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:13:21Z","error":11.0,"lat":48.7477466},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:13:20.000Z,CO 5051466,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":17.64815,"alt":106.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:13:20Z","error":3.0,"lat":47.6851036},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:13:20.000Z,CO 5050569,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":14.0582286,"alt":286.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:13:20Z","error":14.0,"lat":48.1808019},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:13:18.000Z,CO 5050666,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":14.5788998,"alt":25.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:13:18Z","error":12.0,"lat":53.4233772},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:13:17.000Z,CO 5051113,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":14.325237,"alt":254.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:13:17Z","error":13.0,"lat":48.2600698},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:13:10.000Z,CO 5050666,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":14.5788998,"alt":25.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:13:18Z","error":12.0,"lat":53.4233772},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:13:07.000Z,CO 5051887,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":13.8064589,"alt":510.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:13:07Z","error":10.0,"lat":46.5672814},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:12:58.000Z,CO 5051131,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":11.4933341,"alt":581.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:08:43Z","error":13.0,"lat":47.2738262},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:12:55.000Z,CO 5051696,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":14.3200391,"alt":249.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:04:38Z","error":10.0,"lat":48.26912},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:12:48.000Z,CO 5051326,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":9.7326865,"alt":403.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:04:34Z","error":10.0,"lat":47.4595067},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:12:47.000Z,CO 5052218,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":14.3197285,"alt":262.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:11Z","error":9.0,"lat":48.2688562},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:12:45.000Z,CO 5050405,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":14.2755301,"alt":253.0,"time":"2019-09-08T12:13:37Z","error":8.0,"lat":48.2468603},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:12:44.000Z,CO 5050706,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":15.0519029,"alt":124.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:07:07Z","error":13.0,"lat":59.0569164},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:12:42.000Z,CO 5050903,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":15.2678846,"alt":494.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:13:21Z","error":11.0,"lat":48.7477466},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:12:38.000Z,CO 5051303,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":21.9561564,"alt":244.0,"time":"2019-09-10T09:04:08Z","error":11.0,"lat":42.9978861},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:12:37.000Z,CO 5051558,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":13.806765,"alt":514.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:12:37Z","error":6.0,"lat":46.5672868},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:12:37.000Z,CO 5050450,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":14.3195367,"alt":260.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:12:37Z","error":10.0,"lat":48.2695571},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:12:37.000Z,CO 5050450,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":14.3195367,"alt":260.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:12:37Z","error":10.0,"lat":48.2695571},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:12:26.000Z,CO 5050408,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":14.2761472,"alt":280.0,"time":"2019-09-08T12:13:28Z","error":11.0,"lat":48.246868},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:12:25.000Z,CO 5051418,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":15.5343521,"alt":550.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:12:25Z","error":11.0,"lat":48.7483843},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:12:24.000Z,CO 5050556,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":13.0783658,"alt":435.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:12:24Z","error":6.0,"lat":47.7692905},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:12:22.000Z,CO 5052730,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":14.3180816,"alt":251.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:07:29Z","error":14.0,"lat":48.2771342},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:12:11.000Z,CO 5051654,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":15.3298821,"alt":404.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:12:11Z","error":13.0,"lat":47.1319909},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:12:01.000Z,CO 5051400,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":13.4580769,"alt":306.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:12:01Z","error":6.0,"lat":48.4494078},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:11:25.000Z,CO 5050495,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":13.3380207,"alt":423.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:11:25Z","error":14.0,"lat":48.6001935},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:11:15.000Z,CO 5052483,Motion started,c8y_MotionDetected,{"lng":12.0622763,"alt":511.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:11:04Z","error":5.0,"lat":47.4938857},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:11:13.000Z,CO 5052999,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":13.06406,"alt":425.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:11:13Z","error":5.0,"lat":47.8167399},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:11:04.000Z,CO 5052483,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":12.0622763,"alt":511.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:11:04Z","error":5.0,"lat":47.4938857},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:11:01.000Z,CO 5051844,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":11.5022149,"alt":556.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:11:01Z","error":6.0,"lat":47.2765674},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:11:01.000Z,CO 5051920,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":15.0575633,"alt":619.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:44Z","error":13.0,"lat":47.3821983},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:59.000Z,CO 5051679,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":15.0565198,"alt":599.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:59Z","error":14.0,"lat":47.3821768},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:55.000Z,CO 5050630,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":15.0587754,"alt":596.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:55Z","error":14.0,"lat":47.3820239},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:52.000Z,CO 5051844,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":11.5022149,"alt":556.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:11:01Z","error":6.0,"lat":47.2765674},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:51.000Z,CO 5052999,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":13.06406,"alt":425.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:11:13Z","error":5.0,"lat":47.8167399},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:50.000Z,CO 5051921,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":15.0581282,"alt":606.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:36Z","error":6.0,"lat":47.3817808},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:49.000Z,CO 5051679,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":15.0565198,"alt":599.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:59Z","error":14.0,"lat":47.3821768},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:47.000Z,CO 5050630,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":15.0587754,"alt":596.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:55Z","error":14.0,"lat":47.3820239},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:44.000Z,CO 5051920,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":15.0575633,"alt":619.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:44Z","error":13.0,"lat":47.3821983},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:41.000Z,CO 5051088,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":16.6432683,"alt":161.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:41Z","error":8.0,"lat":48.3200659},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:41.000Z,CO 5050020,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":15.9287275,"alt":193.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:41Z","error":8.0,"lat":48.3246395},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:40.000Z,CO 5052681,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":16.4388427,"alt":173.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:40Z","error":8.0,"lat":48.1359584},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:36.000Z,CO 5051921,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":15.0581282,"alt":606.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:36Z","error":6.0,"lat":47.3817808},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:35.000Z,CO 5051406,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":19.0824957,"alt":108.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:35Z","error":7.0,"lat":47.4680908},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:33.000Z,CO 5052676,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":16.4368017,"alt":166.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:33Z","error":7.0,"lat":48.1376442},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:33.000Z,CO 5051767,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":14.3252332,"alt":266.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:33Z","error":6.0,"lat":48.2598268},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:32.000Z,CO 5050710,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":16.4767327,"alt":164.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:32Z","error":5.0,"lat":48.2780685},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:32.000Z,CO 5050565,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":15.0918659,"alt":544.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:32Z","error":12.0,"lat":47.3648989},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:31.000Z,CO 5051820,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":13.3525861,"alt":296.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:31Z","error":12.0,"lat":48.5992175},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:25.000Z,CO 5051464,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":14.3240624,"alt":271.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:25Z","error":12.0,"lat":48.2607067},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:22.000Z,CO 5050655,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":16.4315322,"alt":190.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:01:19Z","error":13.0,"lat":48.1431609},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:20.000Z,CO 5050581,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":13.045159,"alt":422.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:20Z","error":11.0,"lat":47.8110246},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:18.000Z,CO 5051496,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":14.3246911,"alt":271.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:18Z","error":7.0,"lat":48.2602569},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:17.000Z,CO 5051111,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":12.9975553,"alt":398.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:17Z","error":11.0,"lat":47.8261238},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:11.000Z,CO 5052218,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":14.3197285,"alt":262.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:11Z","error":9.0,"lat":48.2688562},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:11.000Z,CO 5052218,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":14.3197285,"alt":262.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:11Z","error":9.0,"lat":48.2688562},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:10.000Z,CO 5050889,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":15.2681143,"alt":526.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:10Z","error":6.0,"lat":48.7494337},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:06.000Z,CO 5050941,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":14.3259313,"alt":254.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:06Z","error":12.0,"lat":48.2594256},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:10:02.000Z,CO 5052698,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":16.4387847,"alt":155.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:02Z","error":12.0,"lat":48.1361544},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:58.000Z,CO 5052994,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":12.9975201,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:09:58Z","error":7.0,"lat":47.8258582},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:58.000Z,CO 5052994,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":12.9975201,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:09:58Z","error":7.0,"lat":47.8258582},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:53.000Z,CO 5050172,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":12.5073911,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:09:53Z","error":6.0,"lat":48.2486859},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:46.000Z,CO 5050036,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":15.5402195,"alt":546.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:09:46Z","error":10.0,"lat":48.7482861},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:42.000Z,CO 5051360,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":15.5412234,"alt":546.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:09:42Z","error":14.0,"lat":48.7482963},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:41.000Z,CO 5052254,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":14.1636504,"alt":497.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:06:33Z","error":3.0,"lat":47.8020297},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:36.000Z,CO 5051886,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":14.0586228,"alt":317.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:09:36Z","error":4.0,"lat":48.1806919},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:36.000Z,CO 5052270,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":14.1637559,"alt":497.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:06:33Z","error":13.0,"lat":47.8015199},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:35.000Z,CO 5050625,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":15.0918728,"alt":551.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:09:35Z","error":14.0,"lat":47.3645485},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:35.000Z,CO 5052165,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":13.8262713,"alt":535.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:09:35Z","error":14.0,"lat":46.5696408},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:32.000Z,CO 5051569,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":15.0962545,"alt":251.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:09:32Z","error":9.0,"lat":48.1569883},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:29.000Z,CO 5051886,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":14.0586228,"alt":317.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:09:36Z","error":4.0,"lat":48.1806919},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:26.000Z,CO 5050079,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":14.3260754,"alt":273.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:09:26Z","error":12.0,"lat":48.259309},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:24.000Z,CO 5051608,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":13.0620331,"alt":443.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:01:33Z","error":4.0,"lat":47.8183534},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:22.000Z,CO 5050636,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":15.7496359,"alt":214.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:09:22Z","error":10.0,"lat":48.3474868},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:13.000Z,CO 5051374,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":16.2192937,"alt":290.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:00:44Z","error":11.0,"lat":47.7971662},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:13.000Z,CO 5050449,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":14.5795362,"alt":1.0,"time":"2019-09-10T11:58:43Z","error":5.0,"lat":53.4248321},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:09.000Z,CO 5052285,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":14.3242807,"alt":279.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:09:09Z","error":11.0,"lat":48.2603765},{"cgmon_TrackVersion":1,"cgmon_AccumulatedTrackLength":22.6966869,"cgmon_PrivateMappingData":"{"MappedCoords":[{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":14.3242807,"Latitude":48.2603765},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":14.324294807614198,"Latitude":48.260394023504993},"Distance":2.05000634,"MappedObject":380848,"Source":352093,"Target":355952,"Length":0.5924257},{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":14.3242807,"Latitude":48.2603765},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":14.324331226025482,"Latitude":48.260439145193047},"Distance":7.32469217,"MappedObject":384713,"Source":355935,"Target":355945,"Length":0.7556776},{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":14.3242807,"Latitude":48.2603765},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":14.324228797434349,"Latitude":48.260311767396061},"Distance":7.55397675,"MappedObject":304419,"Source":278400,"Target":278401,"Length":0.2397567}],"LastCoordUsed":{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":14.3242807,"Latitude":48.2603765},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":14.324228797434349,"Latitude":48.260311767396061},"Distance":7.55397675,"MappedObject":304419,"Source":278400,"Target":278401,"Length":0.2397567}}","cgmon_TrackSegmentIDs":[384707,384708,555759,555760,380849,384723,304419],"cgmon_TrackLength":0.7655877,"time":"2019-09-10T12:13:48.8192688+00:00","cgmon_MappedPoint":{"lng":14.324294807614198,"offset":2.05000634,"lat":48.26039402350499}},N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:09.000Z,CO 5052731,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":14.3181143,"alt":252.0,"time":"2019-09-09T11:59:34Z","error":12.0,"lat":48.2771772},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:08.000Z,CO 5051642,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":14.163689,"alt":477.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:06:20Z","error":10.0,"lat":47.8022479},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:07.000Z,CO 5052267,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":14.1631847,"alt":471.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:06:42Z","error":11.0,"lat":47.80162},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:07.000Z,CO 5051478,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":14.1641262,"alt":497.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:06:15Z","error":7.0,"lat":47.8003779},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:09:01.000Z,CO 5052393,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":13.0494004,"alt":428.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:03:39Z","error":11.0,"lat":47.8189722},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:08:57.000Z,CO 5051020,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":16.2196522,"alt":287.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:01:08Z","error":4.0,"lat":47.7972928},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:08:51.000Z,CO 5050301,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":2.9992244,"alt":-2.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:08:51Z","error":17.0,"lat":43.1661339},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:08:50.000Z,CO 5051365,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":22.169639,"alt":60.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:08:50Z","error":14.0,"lat":48.3902318},{"cgmon_TrackVersion":1,"cgmon_AccumulatedTrackLength":2148.951632500001,"cgmon_PrivateMappingData":"{"MappedCoords":[{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":22.169639,"Latitude":48.3902318},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":22.169632788779996,"Latitude":48.390239719391744},"Distance":0.92519023,"MappedObject":1387861,"Source":1210580,"Target":1236897,"Length":0.8962704},{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":22.169639,"Latitude":48.3902318},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":22.169663000344876,"Latitude":48.390201166002555},"Distance":3.55078237,"MappedObject":1388168,"Source":1236896,"Target":1210581,"Length":0.8169932},{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":22.169639,"Latitude":48.3902318},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":22.169597136212552,"Latitude":48.390285304388065},"Distance":6.21585648,"MappedObject":1388154,"Source":1236890,"Target":1236891,"Length":0.9307675}],"LastCoordUsed":{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":22.169639,"Latitude":48.3902318},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":22.169663000344876,"Latitude":48.390201166002555},"Distance":3.55078237,"MappedObject":1388168,"Source":1236896,"Target":1210581,"Length":0.8169932}}","cgmon_TrackSegmentIDs":[1356958,1356952,1356950,1387850,1387851,1387852,1387853,1387860,1357049,1388168],"cgmon_TrackLength":2.4847659999999996,"time":"2019-09-10T12:11:51.8831079+00:00","cgmon_MappedPoint":{"lng":22.169632788779996,"offset":0.92519023,"lat":48.390239719391744}},N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:08:48.000Z,CO 5050995,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":22.1701667,"alt":99.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:08:48Z","error":11.0,"lat":48.3905254},{"cgmon_TrackVersion":1,"cgmon_AccumulatedTrackLength":3214.932654,"cgmon_PrivateMappingData":"{"MappedCoords":[{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":22.1701667,"Latitude":48.3905254},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":22.170165780943215,"Latitude":48.390526570555245},"Distance":0.14129331,"MappedObject":1357050,"Source":1236896,"Target":1210581,"Length":0.8176738},{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":22.1701667,"Latitude":48.3905254},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":22.170200136954,"Latitude":48.3904827851519},"Distance":4.9398585,"MappedObject":1388164,"Source":1210575,"Target":1236894,"Length":0.7718482},{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":22.1701667,"Latitude":48.3905254},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":22.17013252678472,"Latitude":48.390569018631112},"Distance":5.06730103,"MappedObject":1388168,"Source":1236896,"Target":1210581,"Length":0.8169932}],"LastCoordUsed":{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":22.1701667,"Latitude":48.3905254},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":22.17013252678472,"Latitude":48.390569018631112},"Distance":5.06730103,"MappedObject":1388168,"Source":1236896,"Target":1210581,"Length":0.8169932}}","cgmon_TrackSegmentIDs":[1356958,1356952,1356950,1387850,1387851,1387852,1387853,1387860,1357049,1388168],"cgmon_TrackLength":2.4847659999999996,"time":"2019-09-10T12:11:03.6011894+00:00","cgmon_MappedPoint":{"lng":22.170165780943215,"offset":0.14129331,"lat":48.390526570555245}},N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:08:43.000Z,CO 5051131,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":11.4933341,"alt":581.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:08:43Z","error":13.0,"lat":47.2738262},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:08:43.000Z,CO 5051131,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":11.4933341,"alt":581.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:08:43Z","error":13.0,"lat":47.2738262},{"cgmon_TrackVersion":1,"cgmon_AccumulatedTrackLength":742.7216828999998,"cgmon_PrivateMappingData":"{"MappedCoords":[{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":11.4933341,"Latitude":47.2738262},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":11.49333458398241,"Latitude":47.27383398720535},"Distance":0.86590321,"MappedObject":563332,"Source":502560,"Target":509686,"Length":0.115316},{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":11.4933341,"Latitude":47.2738262},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":11.493332248142858,"Latitude":47.2737926515935},"Distance":3.72901274,"MappedObject":375313,"Source":502559,"Target":346447,"Length":0.150019},{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":11.4933341,"Latitude":47.2738262},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":11.493342343757833,"Latitude":47.2742148522778},"Distance":43.21458138,"MappedObject":309483,"Source":283444,"Target":283445,"Length":0.1669769}],"LastCoordUsed":{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":11.4933341,"Latitude":47.2738262},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":11.493332248142858,"Latitude":47.2737926515935},"Distance":3.72901274,"MappedObject":375313,"Source":502559,"Target":346447,"Length":0.150019}}","cgmon_TrackSegmentIDs":[],"cgmon_TrackLength":0.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:11:24.3216749+00:00","cgmon_MappedPoint":{"lng":11.49333458398241,"offset":0.86590321,"lat":47.27383398720535}},N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:08:35.000Z,CO 5050866,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":14.3215058,"alt":267.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:08:35Z","error":4.0,"lat":48.2636151},{"cgmon_TrackVersion":1,"cgmon_AccumulatedTrackLength":4978.0674611,"cgmon_PrivateMappingData":"{"MappedCoords":[{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":14.3215058,"Latitude":48.2636151},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":14.321510549351785,"Latitude":48.263617838889992},"Distance":0.43737558,"MappedObject":555759,"Source":278547,"Target":355946,"Length":0.0388289},{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":14.3215058,"Latitude":48.2636151},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":14.321524282808905,"Latitude":48.263622620442391},"Distance":1.53920182,"MappedObject":384719,"Source":278547,"Target":355950,"Length":0.0197342},{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":14.3215058,"Latitude":48.2636151},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":14.321537838128785,"Latitude":48.263639596569256},"Distance":3.3491457,"MappedObject":384714,"Source":355943,"Target":355950,"Length":0.0222092}],"LastCoordUsed":{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":14.3215058,"Latitude":48.2636151},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":14.321524282808905,"Latitude":48.263622620442391},"Distance":1.53920182,"MappedObject":384719,"Source":278547,"Target":355950,"Length":0.0197342}}","cgmon_TrackSegmentIDs":[384707,384708,384719],"cgmon_TrackLength":0.0800117,"time":"2019-09-10T12:10:46.0909247+00:00","cgmon_MappedPoint":{"lng":14.321510549351785,"offset":0.43737558,"lat":48.26361783888999}},N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:08:33.000Z,CO 5051872,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":9.1817503,"alt":317.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:08:33Z","error":7.0,"lat":48.8762001},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:08:33.000Z,CO 5051872,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":9.1817503,"alt":317.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:08:33Z","error":7.0,"lat":48.8762001},{"cgmon_TrackVersion":1,"cgmon_AccumulatedTrackLength":2164.2141009,"cgmon_PrivateMappingData":"{"MappedCoords":[{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":9.1817503,"Latitude":48.8762001},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":9.1817456392881081,"Latitude":48.876203640311175},"Distance":0.48084995,"MappedObject":271673,"Source":253908,"Target":253909,"Length":0.7860666},{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":9.1817503,"Latitude":48.8762001},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":9.1817918660285152,"Latitude":48.876168565239695},"Distance":4.28556164,"MappedObject":271808,"Source":25656,"Target":253942,"Length":0.7500596},{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":9.1817503,"Latitude":48.8762001},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":9.1817007140337878,"Latitude":48.876240680236577},"Distance":5.3165598,"MappedObject":53249,"Source":65777,"Target":65778,"Length":0.7357852}],"LastCoordUsed":{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":9.1817503,"Latitude":48.8762001},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":9.1817918660285152,"Latitude":48.876168565239695},"Distance":4.28556164,"MappedObject":271808,"Source":25656,"Target":253942,"Length":0.7500596}}","cgmon_TrackSegmentIDs":[271722,271721,271808],"cgmon_TrackLength":0.8470511000000001,"time":"2019-09-10T12:13:19.9039541+00:00","cgmon_MappedPoint":{"lng":9.181745639288108,"offset":0.48084995,"lat":48.876203640311175}},N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:08:33.000Z,CO 5052718,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":14.3244721,"alt":261.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:08:33Z","error":7.0,"lat":48.2604709},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:08:32.000Z,CO 5051786,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":15.0934742,"alt":520.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:08:32Z","error":8.0,"lat":47.3602516},{"cgmon_TrackVersion":1,"cgmon_AccumulatedTrackLength":955.3499446999999,"cgmon_PrivateMappingData":"{"MappedCoords":[{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":15.0934742,"Latitude":47.3602516},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":15.093487876023856,"Latitude":47.360256466815642},"Distance":1.12824369,"MappedObject":543110,"Source":500082,"Target":495975,"Length":0.01726},{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":15.0934742,"Latitude":47.3602516},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":15.093411454625754,"Latitude":47.360229436743339},"Distance":5.16984112,"MappedObject":543115,"Source":495974,"Target":495978,"Length":0.1121813},{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":15.0934742,"Latitude":47.3602516},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":15.0935137,"Latitude":47.3601839},"Distance":8.09452479,"MappedObject":543111,"Source":495975,"Target":495976,"Length":0.0788724}],"LastCoordUsed":{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":15.0934742,"Latitude":47.3602516},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":15.093411454625754,"Latitude":47.360229436743339},"Distance":5.16984112,"MappedObject":543115,"Source":495974,"Target":495978,"Length":0.1121813}}","cgmon_TrackSegmentIDs":[391386,391385,391384,543119,543118,543117,543116,543115],"cgmon_TrackLength":1.1705694,"time":"2019-09-10T12:13:03.6134601+00:00","cgmon_MappedPoint":{"lng":15.093487876023856,"offset":1.12824369,"lat":47.36025646681564}},N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:08:31.000Z,CO 5051710,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":13.5639021,"alt":90.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:08:31Z","error":5.0,"lat":55.9589473},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:08:25.000Z,CO 5050045,Location updated,c8y_LocationUpdate,{"lng":16.1018443,"alt":459.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:08:25Z","error":6.0,"lat":47.5827225},{"cgmon_TrackVersion":1,"cgmon_AccumulatedTrackLength":8331.496018900007,"cgmon_PrivateMappingData":"{"MappedCoords":[{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":16.1018443,"Latitude":47.5827225},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":16.101728908989276,"Latitude":47.58270774508388},"Distance":8.7637246,"MappedObject":378585,"Source":349716,"Target":349717,"Length":0.2371537},{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":16.1018443,"Latitude":47.5827225},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":16.1015723781081,"Latitude":47.58268623088636},"Distance":20.67398342,"MappedObject":522532,"Source":349716,"Target":479666,"Length":0.3900395}],"LastCoordUsed":{"OriginalCoords":{"Longitude":16.1018443,"Latitude":47.5827225},"MappedCoords":{"Longitude":16.101728908989276,"Latitude":47.58270774508388},"Distance":8.7637246,"MappedObject":378585,"Source":349716,"Target":349717,"Length":0.2371537}}","cgmon_TrackSegmentIDs":[],"cgmon_TrackLength":0.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:09:18.2576463+00:00","cgmon_MappedPoint":{"lng":16.101728908989276,"offset":8.7637246,"lat":47.58270774508388}},N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:08:19.000Z,CO 5050276,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":14.9097604,"alt":292.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:04:01Z","error":12.0,"lat":48.1208139},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:08:11.000Z,CO 5051153,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":15.2786873,"alt":476.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:01:48Z","error":10.0,"lat":47.4239228},N/A,N/A,N/A
2019-09-10T12:08:02.000Z,CO 5051710,Lifesign,cgmon_Lifesign,{"lng":13.5639021,"alt":90.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:08:31Z","error":5.0,"lat":55.9589473},N/A,N/A,N/A
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that the commas inside your `json` string are being treated as delimiters. You should modify the input data (if you don't have direct access to the file, you can always read the contents into a list of strings using `open` first).

Here are a few modification options that you can try:

**Option 1: Quote `json` string with single quote**

Use a single quote (or another character that doesn't otherwise appear in your data) as a quote character for your `json` string.

```sh
>> cat data.csv
Time,location,labelA,labelB
2019-09-10,'{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8}',nan,nan
```

Then use `quotechar="'"` when you read the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df=pd.read_csv('data.csv', converters={'location':json.loads}, header=0, quotechar="'")
```

**Option 2: Quote `json` string with double quote and escape**

If the single quote can't be used, you *can* actually use the double quote as the `quotechar`, as long as your escape the quotes inside the `json` string:

```sh
>> cat data.csv
Time,location,labelA,labelB
2019-09-10,"{""lng"":12.9,""alt"":413.0,""time"":""2019-09-10"",""error"":7.0,""lat"":17.8}",nan,nan
```

Notice that this now matches the format of the question you linked.

```
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv', converters={'location':json.loads}, header=0, quotechar='"')
```

**Option 3: Change the delimiter**

Use a different character, for example the `|` as the delimiter

```sh
>> cat data.csv
Time|location|labelA|labelB
2019-09-10|{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8}|nan|nan
```

Now use the `sep` argument to specify the new delimiter:

```
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv', converters={'location':json.loads}, header=0, sep="|")
```

---

Each of these methods produce the same output:

```
print(df)
#   Time        location                                            labelA  labelB
#0  2019-09-10  {u'lat': 17.8, u'lng': 12.9, u'error': 7.0, u'...   NaN     NaN
```

Once you have that, you can expand the `location` column using one of the methods described in [Flatten JSON column in a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822874/i-want-to-flatten-json-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

```
new_df = df.join(pd.io.json.json_normalize(df["location"])).drop(["location"], axis=1)
print(new_df)
#   Time        labelA  labelB  alt    error  lat   lng   time
#0  2019-09-10  NaN     NaN     413.0  7.0    17.8  12.9  2019-09-10
```

Answer (score 10):

## Fix the file:

- Unfortunately, the file is difficult to read because each row contains a `dict`, whose `key-value` pairs are separated by commas.
- The easiest way to resolve the issue, is change the separators outside of each `dict`, from `,` to `|`.
- The following code will read the existing file

  - It assumes, the first row is the header, use `.replace(',', '|')`
  - Remaining rows will use a regular expression to replace `,` outside of `{}`
  - Each line will be written to a new file.

### Code:

#### Data:

```py
Time,location,labelA,labelB
2019-09-10,{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8},{"ack":123,"bar":456},{"foo":123,"bar":456}
2019-09-10,{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8},nan,nan
2019-09-10,{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8},{"ack":123,"bar":456},{"foo":123,"bar":456}
2019-09-10,{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8},nan,nan
2019-09-10,{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8},{"ack":123,"bar":456},{"foo":123,"bar":456}
2019-09-10,{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8},nan,nan
2019-09-10,{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8},{"ack":123,"bar":456},{"foo":123,"bar":456}
2019-09-10,{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8},nan,nan
```

- `Path.cwd()` assumes `current working directory`, if this is not the case:

  - `Path('c:/some_path_to_my_file') / 'file_name.poo'` can be used
- [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is part of the standard library
- [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)

#### File repair:

```py
import re
from pathlib import Path

p = Path.cwd() / 'test.csv'
p2 = Path.cwd() / 'test2.csv'

with p.open('r') as f:
    with p2.open('w') as f2:
        for cnt, line in enumerate(f):
            if cnt == 0:
                line = line.replace(',', '|')
            else:
                line = re.sub(r',(?=(((?!\}).)*\{)|[^\{\}]*$)', '|', line)
            f2.write(line)
```

#### New file:

```py
Time|location|labelA|labelB
2019-09-10|{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8}|{"ack":123,"bar":456}|{"foo":123,"bar":456}
2019-09-10|{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8}|nan|nan
2019-09-10|{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8}|{"ack":123,"bar":456}|{"foo":123,"bar":456}
2019-09-10|{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8}|nan|nan
2019-09-10|{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8}|{"ack":123,"bar":456}|{"foo":123,"bar":456}
2019-09-10|{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8}|nan|nan
2019-09-10|{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8}|{"ack":123,"bar":456}|{"foo":123,"bar":456}
2019-09-10|{"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8}|nan|nan
```

### Parse the new file:

- Now the columns will be properly separated by `.read_csv`
- However, the `location`, `labelA` and `labelB` columns are `str`

  - Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert to `dict`
  - `literal_eval` won't work on `nan`, so replace `nan` with `{}`
- `for col in df.columns[1:]:` loops through each of the columns and:

  - `try-except` will catch any columns that are not properly formed
  - converts them from `str` to `dict`
  - separates the `keys` into columns
  - `concats` the columns to the existing dataframe
  - `drops` the old column

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.read_csv('test2.csv', sep='|')
print(df)

       Time                                                             location                 labelA                 labelB
 2019-09-10  {"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8}  {"ack":123,"bar":456}  {"foo":123,"bar":456}
 2019-09-10  {"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8}                    NaN                    NaN
 2019-09-10  {"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8}  {"ack":123,"bar":456}  {"foo":123,"bar":456}
 2019-09-10  {"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8}                    NaN                    NaN
 2019-09-10  {"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8}  {"ack":123,"bar":456}  {"foo":123,"bar":456}
 2019-09-10  {"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8}                    NaN                    NaN
 2019-09-10  {"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8}  {"ack":123,"bar":456}  {"foo":123,"bar":456}
 2019-09-10  {"lng":12.9,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10","error":7.0,"lat":17.8}                    NaN                    NaN


for col in df.columns[1:]:
    try:
        df[col].fillna('{}', inplace=True)
        df[col] = df[col].apply(literal_eval)
        df = pd.concat([df, df[col].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
        df.drop(columns=[col], inplace=True)
    except (SyntaxError, ValueError) as e:
        print(f'{col}: {e}')


print(df)

       Time   lng    alt        time  error   lat    ack    bar    foo    bar
 2019-09-10  12.9  413.0  2019-09-10    7.0  17.8  123.0  456.0  123.0  456.0
 2019-09-10  12.9  413.0  2019-09-10    7.0  17.8    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
 2019-09-10  12.9  413.0  2019-09-10    7.0  17.8  123.0  456.0  123.0  456.0
 2019-09-10  12.9  413.0  2019-09-10    7.0  17.8    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
 2019-09-10  12.9  413.0  2019-09-10    7.0  17.8  123.0  456.0  123.0  456.0
 2019-09-10  12.9  413.0  2019-09-10    7.0  17.8    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
 2019-09-10  12.9  413.0  2019-09-10    7.0  17.8  123.0  456.0  123.0  456.0
 2019-09-10  12.9  413.0  2019-09-10    7.0  17.8    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

### Literal Eval Notes:

- Pandas has methods for importing data in many forms, such as `dict` or `list`.
- However, `read_csv` doesn't interprete containers (e.g. `dict`) well, they are interpreted as a string, unless you specify the `converters` parameter (`pd.read_csv('test3.csv', sep='|', converters={'a': literal_eval})`.
- `literal_eval` will not work on a column comprised of both containers and `strings` or `NaN`, unless the `string` is only numeric (e.g. '8654')
- Part of the code above, first replaced all `nan` with a `{}` so `literal_eval` wouldn't have an error.
- Given the following mixed column example:

```py
column_a
{"ack":123,"bar":456}
some string
{"ack":123,"bar":456}
some string
{"ack":123,"bar":456}
some string
```

- `literal_eval` will throw `ValueError: malformed node or string:`
- This difference between the two solutions is the other solution fixes one column, whereas this solution was implemented in such a way as to fix all the columns and remove the necessity of reading only the first 100 rows.
- You can forgo the loop to fix all the columns and just fix the `location` column, if it is all `dicts`.  Use the following code:

```py
df['location'] = df['location'].apply(literal_eval)
df = pd.concat([df, df['location'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

## Note about the actual data `test100v1.csv`:

- the `location` column is not formed properly

  - `'{"lng":12.9975201,alt:413.0,"time:""2019-09-10T12:09:58Z""",error:7.0,lat:47.8258582}'`
- Here is the expected form:

  - `'{"lng":12.9975201,"alt":413.0,"time":"2019-09-10T12:09:58Z","error":7.0,"lat":47.8258582}'`

### Fix the `location` column:

- The `location` column is `Position` in the real data

```py
def fix_pos(x):
    word_dict = {'alt': '"alt"',
                 '"time:"': '"time":',
                 '"",error:': ',"error":',
                 'lat': '"lat"'}
    for k, v in word_dict.items():
        x = x.replace(k, v)
    return x

df.Position = df.Position.apply(lambda x: fix_pos(x))
```

- Use the following loop with the real data file.
- `Zeit`, `device`, `Text` & `Type` don't need to be processed
- `Position` is at `index` 4.

```py
for col in df.columns[4:]:
    try:
        df[col].fillna('{}', inplace=True)
        df[col] = df[col].apply(literal_eval)
        df = pd.concat([df, df[col].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
        df.drop(columns=[col], inplace=True)
    except (SyntaxError, ValueError) as e:
        print(f'{col}: {e}')
```

- The loop that applies `literal_eval` to all columns has been updated with `try-except`

  - If there's an `exception` the `column` name and error message will be printed out.
  - There are a total of 64 columns in the real data, most of them are **Furchtbar**.

#### Errors:

- These are the errors for all the columns in the supplied `csv` file.

```py
device: unexpected EOF while parsing (<unknown>, line 1)
Text: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x00000203B8473C08>
Typ: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x00000203BE217E08>
Data: unexpected EOF while parsing (<unknown>, line 1)
Data1: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
Data2: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 8: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 9: unexpected EOF while parsing (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 10: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 11: unexpected EOF while parsing (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 12: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 13: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 14: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 15: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 16: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 17: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 18: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 19: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 20: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 21: unexpected EOF while parsing (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 22: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 23: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 24: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 25: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 26: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
Unnamed: 27: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199650/discussion-between-physiker-and-trenton-m).